# Remove /category/ base wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So this is my url: `http://site.com/category/my-nice-category/my-nice-subcategory/` how can I remove `category` from the URL, i've tried alot of things and  plugins but doesn't work.

Best Regards,

Comment: Well both...but I can paste the url's..so that's not a problem...but when I try to access `http://site.com/my-nice-category/my-nice-subcategory/` it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved use this: http://www.fortes.com/projects/wordpress/top-level-cats

Answer (score 0):

Presently I am doing it by a [WordPress plugin](http://www.wordpressians.com/remove-category-slug-base-wordpress-urls/).

Hopes it may help you!

Comment: You must disclose affiliation with external links.